# Can´t create XSD from exe

Tags: c#, xsd

I have a simple program that I want to create an schema from:

```
public class Program
{
    public Foo f = new Bar();
}
public abstract class Foo { }
public class Bar : Foo {}
```

The program compiles fine against .NET 4.0 (x86) on a 64bit-system. It has no external references to any other library (instead mscorlib of course). Now I want to create an XSD from that assembly using this command:

```
xsd pathToAssembly/ConsoleApplication1.exe
```

which gives me this:

> Microsoft (R) Xml Schemas/DataTypes support utility
>   [Microsoft (R) .NET Framework, Version 4.0.30319.1]
>   Copyright
>   (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

However I get an error:

> Could not load file or assembly 'ConsoleApplication1.exe' or one of
>   its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an
>   incorrect format.

which is usually caused by different runtimes. However as my project uses .NET 4 and XSD-tool (obviously) also, I´m confused why I can´t create the schema.

I already tried to call XSD from the directory where the assembly is located which causes the same error.

I´m using XSD from Visual Studio 2010 within a 64bit Windows 8.1.

EDIT: The path to XSD is this: `C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft SDKs/Windows/v7.0A/Bin/NETFX 4.0 Tools/xsd.exe`

Comment: The error message points toward a 32/64 bit issue. Is it a 64-bit executable, as opposed to, say, AnyCPU?

Comment: No, it compiles for x86.

Comment: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/2a5f085a-eaf5-4c2c-9d1d-ebfcaecc21d6/xsdexe-does-not-work-for-x86-dlls-on-a-windows-x64-system?forum=xmlandnetfx

Comment: Oh, quite annyoing, isn´t it? Thanks however, @CodeCaster

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a 32 and a 64 bit version of Xsd.exe, and the one that's being run depends on your path variable.

For example the Windows SDK v7.0A puts the tools at these paths:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Bin\xsd.exe
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Bin\x64\xsd.exe
```

Now when you run the either of those:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Bin\xsd.exe" "ConsoleApplication1.exe"
```

It'll give the error shown. That's because that assembly (Xsd.exe, not ConsoleApplicaiton1.exe) is compiled against "AnyCPU" and will run in 64 bit on a 64 bit system. This will cause the error you see, because a 64 bit process can't load a 32 bit assembly.

You can circumvent this by forcing the 32-bit Xsd.exe to be x86 as well. You can do so from an elevated command prompt:

```
corflags "Path\To\xsd.exe" /32BITREQ+ /Force
```

Note that this will invalidate the signature of the assembly, but that won't affect its functionality. You'll want to do this not on the original Xsd.exe, but on a copy of it.

Now this assembly always runs as a 32-bit process and can happily load your x86 assembly.

Comment: However one last question: what do you mean by "invalidate the signature of the assembly"? Mine is signed, so will this affect this?

Comment: By setting that flag on the Xsd.exe you invalidate the signature of Xsd.exe, which shouldn't be a problem. It doesn't affect your assembly.